# Python MySQL add rows to ONE variable

Tags: python, mysql, variables, rows

I want to store the result of a MySQL query in one variable (Python)

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM movies"
result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
    movies = row[1]

print(movies)
```

(Only prints the last row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`movies = row[1]` here `movies` is a variable, will have only the last element from the for loop.

you need to create a list `movies`

`movies = []`

and do

```
for row in result:
    movies.append(row[1])

print(movies)
```